# Spring, jQuery: how to achieve the same behavior?

Tags: jquery, spring

I'd like my jQuery script behave as a direct link calling (what I'm pretty sure that is not a hard thing), which I'm explaining next:

1. I have a .jsp page with a jeasyui component (a datagrid), listing projects in my application, that can be requested in one of its rows to call a .GET method in controller in order to set up a certain object (a Project class, in this case) and call another .jsp page, to do update tasks in this instance (very usual, in fact...).
2. When I call directly the method in the listing .jsp page through an , the controller process the HTTP GET request and returns to the update .jsp page, normally.
3. When I try to do the same (step 2) through jQuery (in order to use the refered DataGrid), the controller method is called, parameter is correctly passed to, but response doesn't trace to .jsp update page.

Let's go to the codes:

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Project setUpForm(HttpServletRequest req, 
                            HttpServletResponse resp,
                                @RequestParam(value="id", required=false) 
                                    Long id, Model model, ModelMap modelMap){

    ... do stuff ...
    /* CONTROLER IS WORKING FINE */

    if(id==null){
        //that's a new project!
        Project project = new Project();
        return project;
    } else {
        //an ID was passed and means an existing one!
        Project project = mpService.getProjectById(id);
        return project;
    }   
}
```

**list JSP page (project listing)**

```
<!-- ... datagrid code... next is working fine! (just a test to controller) -->

    <a href="<c:url value='project/MaintainProjectFrm?id=11'/>"></a>

<!-- ... but, when I call jsp page through JQuery, what I must do in order to use dataGrid component (through an event), controller is called but editing jsp page is not returned -->

            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton"
            iconCls="icon-edit" plain="true" onclick="projectEdit()">
            Edit </a>
```

**JavaScript file:**

```
function projectEdit() {
    var row = $('#dgProject').datagrid('getSelected'); //gets DataGrid object and its selected row
    if (row) {
     // at this point controller is called correctly but response doesn't go to the edit/update page.
        $.get("project/MaintainProjetoFrm", {id: row.id});
    }
}
```

Have you any idea on what could be happening?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you sure that you should you `$.get`? Isn't it posted through `$.post`?

Comment: Are you sure you have a `<th field="id">...</th>`. Otherwise it wont know what what `row.id` is.

Comment: @RoySchoep, yes, I want to use GETs for retrieving a new form (whatever new project or update) and POSTs just for create, update and delete. This adhere to this aproach: http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/web/5/

Comment: @Will, the ID is OK, everything is Ok. The problem is that, when I call the Controller throught jquery, the returning of the method doesn't redirect to the new/update jsp page. This problem doesn't occours when I call controller with a simple <a href>. I quite sure that's a simple issue on jquery usage rather spring or controller's design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For somebody having a similar problem:

The behavior is achieved using `window.location.replace` method from javascript on .jsp page or .js file referenced by that.

```
$('#dgProject').datagrid({
    onCheck: function(rowIndex,rowData){
         window.location.replace("/path/MaintainProjectFrm?id="+rowData.id);
    }
});
```